# C#/.NET 3D graphics library for creating coloured cubes

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

I need to be able to do the following:

- display a series of coloured cubes on the screen
- adjust the transparency of each cube based on an intensity value
- adjust/pan/zoom/navigate the view

I'd like to use a library that has the shallowest learning curve for creating such an application, ideally something which is easy to use in the C#/.NET world.

I've looked at DirectX and some of its .NET wrappers such as [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) and [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/).

But I'm wondering if a game engine, such as [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net), would be easier to use for such simple requirements?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know [Eyeshot](http://www.devdept.com)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WPF for such things. How hard it is depends on what your 3d models are, but if you only need cubes, that shouldn't be much of a problem.
Check this link for example - https://stuff.seans.com/2008/08/13/drawing-a-cube-in-wpf/

Code is pretty much self explanatory but basically you have `Viewport3D` which is complete scene and then there you have defined camera (what camera "sees" is what it will be displayed) and couple of `ModelVisual3D` objects. First one contains light (without it, cube would be completely black) and second one is your cube.
Cube is defined by mesh and material. Mash has vertices (`Positions` property) and triangles. Positions are points defined by coordinates and triangles are triplets of above mentioned points. You can make other 3D shapes this way, not only cubes.
Now, in most simple form, only thing you need to worry is `Positions` property. Changing numbers there you can change size and position of cube.
To add more cubes, you will need more `ModelVisual3D` objects.

Once you get familiar by manually changing these values, there shouldn't be a problem to programmatically do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk) allows for OpenGL calls within a .NET language.  It's quite well established and lends itself to porting to Mono etc.  It also allows you to have (relatively) low level control of the rendering.

Alternatively if you just want C# control of rendering, how about [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) which will abstract away most of the details for you and just let you concentrate on the code (also portable to different OS's)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to use a library that has the shallowest learning curve for
>   creating such an application, ideally something which is easy to use
>   in the C#/.NET world.

Based on the above I would go for MonoGame which implements the Microsoft XNA 4 API and should be pretty easy to pick up and go. It was designed specifically for the .NET framework and as such should be easy to pick up for someone who already programs in .NET and knows a little bit about graphics. Going for a lower level approach such as OpenGL or DirectX is likely to take more time and effort not to mention a steeper learning curve.